# Replace string regardless of capitals

Tags: c#, string, biml

I have this variable defined:

```
string string2remove ="slimshady";
```

I have a string `filePath` that has the value `myNameIsslimshady`

`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath.Replace(string2remove,""))` gives me `mynameis`

However, when filePath has the value `myNameIsSlimShady`
`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath.Replace(string2remove,""))` gives me `myNameIsSlimShady`

Apparently replace cares about capitalisation. No problem! I will make filePath all lowercase using `ToLower()`.

`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath.ToLower().Replace(string2remove,""))`

Now I get `mynameisslimshady`. All in lower but slimshady still has not left the building.

How do I get the replace to ignore capitalisation?

Full code below

```
<FileFormats>
    <#
    foreach (string filePath in myFiles)
    {
            bool fHasSpace = filePath.Contains(" ");
            if  (fHasSpace) {} else {
          
            #>

    <FlatFileFormat Name="FlatFileFormat_<#=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath.ToLower().Replace(string2remove,""))#>" RowDelimiter="<#=delimiter#>" ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="true" IsUnicode="false">
        <Columns>
            <# 
                 
                StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(filePath);
                myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Replace(separator,"").Split(delimiter);
                 myFile.Close();
                 
                // to determine the column delimiter 
                int columnCount = 0;
                string columnDelimiter = "";
 
                    foreach(string myColumn in myColumns)
                    {
                        string str_delimiter = delimiter.ToString();
                        columnCount++;
                        bool finalColumn = columnCount == myColumns.Length;
                        if (finalColumn)
                        {
                            columnDelimiter = "CRLF";
                        }
                        else
                        {   columnDelimiter = str_delimiter;
                        }
                #>
                <Column Name="<#=myColumn#>" DataType = "<#=imp_datatype#>" Length="<#=imp_length#>" Delimiter="<#=columnDelimiter#>"></Column>
                <# } #>
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
            <#}}#>
    </FileFormats>
```

Comment: It's not really a replace, but maybe it works in this case?

`filePath.Remove(filePath.IndexOf(string2remove, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), string2remove.Length);` If this is what you're looking for I can write up an answer for you. But I'm not sure if this was what you are asking for.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem with your example input. Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: `string stan = filePath.ToLower().Replace(string2remove.ToLower(),"");` and then print that value before you do your get file name operation. (Mobile atm)

Comment: please explain the problem clearly, I started to read, a big mess... anything is clear... paths, slimshady, strange # code... what is all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
fileName=Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath), string2remove,"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the overload that has a StringComparison parameter.

This code writes myNameIs to the console:

```
        string toReplace = "slimshady";
        string original = "myNameIsSlimShady";
        string outcome = original.Replace(toReplace, "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        Console.WriteLine(outcome);   // outputs myNameIs
```